How to move an absolute positioned element to front layer of the app? (Angular v.17)
I am having an issue with layout layers I guess.
I have a mat-dialog component, which has a form inside of it with select (custom made, not mat-select).
The dropdown of the select has position absolute, but it is still being cut by mat-dialog.

Also the same type of behavior goes with mat-tabs.
I have tried to play with overflow and z-index, but as I don't actually understand the origin of the problem, I can't really blindly fix it.
The expecting result:

no scroll in mat-dialog related to opened dropdown, but with opportunity to show itself if in the form will be more content;
dropdown is shown with height according to its styles, overflowing the container.

Does anybody know the backdoor fot this issue?


You can either have one of the two, scrollbar or dropdown visible outside, not both, also share the library you used for the select is it ng-select?

@NarenMurali , nope, it is just a custom select made from div's with absolute positioning (legacy code).
Should I try ng-select or material select?

prefer material select, reason provided in my answer below.

Since you want a scrollbar inside the dialog, the dropdown should be placed on the root of the html, so the simplest option will be to.
Prefer material select, second choice is ng-select, but material has a better community and a better option in my opinion.

Thanks for the answer. The solution of using material select worked for me.

When you create the mat-dialog you can indicate a panelClass. If this pannelClass is, e.g. custom-pop-up you can add in styles.scss some like
.custom-pop-up .mat-mdc-dialog-surface{
  overflow-y:visible;
}

This change the overflow-y (by defect is auto)
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  panelClass:'custom-pop-up', //<--this
  data: {....},
});

see stackblitz (when focus show a large div)
